# Pandas add multiple columns same time

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to perform an apply and add 2 columns for each row. Is possible to do it in a single apply?

```
df['message_segments'], df['total_cost'] = df['smssid'].apply(lambda sms_sid: _append_twilio_info(sms_sid))

def _append_twilio_info(sms_sid):
    twilio_sms_message = _get_sms_info_on_twilio(sms_sid)
    return twilio_sms_message.num_segments, twilio_sms_message.price
```

This way is not working. Sometimes the column `total_cost` get the value from column `num_segments`.

Example:

```
                              smssid    ...     total_cost
1  SM42ea979fb9374bf08c693fc90aabcd5    ...              4
3  SMc09ec3cc8711431480aabjsebjbejad    ...       -0.06000
```

Comment: Maybe use the newish `df.assign()`?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky to be sure, because your function is not fully provided, but I tested this on some made-up data, where the lambda function outputs a tuple (one tuple for each row) and this worked:

```
df[['message_segments','total_cost']] = pd.Dataframe(df['smssid'].apply(lambda sms_sid: _append_twilio_info(sms_sid)).tolist())
```